# get local printers to setup in my web application for different printing objects

Tags: javascript, printing

I am searching for an extension like the former "JS Print Setup" in Firefox, which gives me the local installed printers as JavaScript variables. And which I am capable of printing without Print Dialog to specific printers.

For example:
We have to print on two printers from the application. The first one is a label printer and the second one is a normal A4 printer. I need to setup one printer for the label printing and one printer for the A4 printing.

Is there someting like the former JS Print Setup which is working on actual Browsers? Or is there another possibilty to solve my problem?

Thanks,
Nico